# I want to create a time class that has different units of time as methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a time class that would have "quantity" and "unit" as its inputs

i.e.

```
x = time_input(1.5, 'days')
```

I would like to be able to have different units of time available as methods so that any time can be quickly converter to any other unit of time

i.e.

```
x.seconds()
x.hours()
```

I have a dictionary of units of time and their corresponding value in seconds (the smallest unit of time I'm working with) so that any time entered can be converted to seconds

```
time_dict = {'seconds': 1, 'minutes': 60, 'hours': 3600, 'days': 86400, 'weeks': 604800, 'years': 31556952, 'decades': 315569520, 'centuries': 3155695200, 'millennia': 31556952000}
```

So conversion from one unit of time to another is just a matter of multiplying the quantity by the unit (in seconds) and dividing by the desired unit (in seconds). My question is:

1. Is a dictionary the appropriate tool to store these values?
2. Can a dictionary be built into a class for this purpose and is that even a desirable thing to do?
3. Does this tool already exist somewhere?

Comment: 3. Yes, something _very_ similar exists. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Comment: Isn't timedelta used to calculate the duration between two given times? Can it arbitrarily convert from one unit of time to another in a similar manor as what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. <strike>Probably not. Since it's a simple mathematical operation, you can just store the number of seconds as an integer (to avoid floating-point precision issues) and then divide by the correct factor in each function</strike>
   I misread your original question. Yes, a dict would be an appropriate way to store these numbers. Or you could define individual constants in the class. Note, though, that a year doesn't always have 365 days.
2. <strike>Not quite sure what you mean by *dictionary being built into a class*. Just create a class like so</strike> Yes, you could include such a dict in a class like so:

```
class timespan:
    _multiplier = {'seconds': 1, 'minutes': 60, 'hours': 3600, 'days': 3600*24, 'weeks': 3600*24*7}
    def __init__(self, number, unit):
        self.num_seconds = number * timespan._multiplier[unit]
    
    def days(self):
        return self.num_seconds / timespan._multiplier['days']

    def hours(self):
        return self.num_seconds / timespan._multiplier['hours']
```

3. Yes. Something *very* similar exists in [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). You can convert a duration to a `timedelta` object, and then `timedelta.total_seconds()` will give you the number of seconds. After that, finding number of days, etc is just math. `timedelta` even simplifies it for you by implementing the division operation. For example, `timedelta(days=1) / timedelta(hours=1)` gives `24.0`

Comment: Thank you for the information. Regarding the issue you mentioned about the number of days in a year, that wouldn't be a concern for this use case because I'm not using a particular year like 2020 (which could involve leap years and such). 1 year would just be a standard year with a standard number of seconds since I'm dealing with units of time and not actual dates

Comment: Also, what is the significance of the underscore in front of _multiplier?

Comment: @StephenWilliams by convention, a single leading underscore indicates a "private variable" https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles

Comment: Of course, because Python doesn't _truly_ support private variables, it's essentiallly just a "weak internal use indicator", as the PEP calls it.

Comment: Got it! Thank you. I was able to get what I wanted pretty easily https://pastebin.com/z1qfFv8W